# Upperbound with Frobenius and Euclidean Norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

Given $x^TAy$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Does the inequality below hold?

$$\vert x^TAy \vert \le \Vert x\Vert_F\Vert y\Vert_F \Vert A\Vert_2$$

where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_F:=\sqrt{\mbox{trace}(A^TA)}$ is the Frobenius norm and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2:=\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)}$ is the spectral norm.

Comment: It does ${}{}{}$.